# Probability - Cov of two random variable $(X,Y)$

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, covariance

Let $(X,Y)$ be a 2d random variable.
Suppose:
$\mathbb{P}(X\in[-1,15])=1$
$\mathbb{E}[Y|X=t]=t^2$
What above could be value for the common $\mathbb{V}$ar of X,Y, which means: $\mathbb{C}_{ov}(X,Y)$
A: $0$
B: $-16$
C: $8$
D: All possible.

To be honest, I really tried this, but I have no idea where to start with it, it is a test exercise and I have no idea how to progress with it.
There was a close question like that, but with $\mathbb{P}(X\in[1,10])=1$ and the solution was $8$.
and another similliar $\mathbb{P}(X\in[-10,-1])=1$ with solution of -16.
again, without knowing why, on both of them

My thoughts regarding the question I asked is maybe D, but I really have no idea why.

Comment: The solution seems to be wrong. If $P(X=c)=1$ for some constant $c$, then $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) = \mathrm{Cov}(c,c^2) = 0$

Comment: To be honest, no Idea how you got that info, about the equality of 0.  
But about the solutions, I double checked and it is as I wrote. Are you sure? since as I said, there was two similiar questions with a little difference and thus the solution are different

Comment: And thanks for trying to help :) This question is very complex, so I can understand why it is "empty" ( I have no idea how to "attack" this question )

Comment: $\mathrm{Cov}(c,c^2) = E([c-E(c)][c^2-E(c^2)]) = E[ (c-c)(c^2-c^2)]$ And we also have $E(Y\mid X) = X^2$, so yes.

Comment: Oh, the first part I actually understood.
The second, I am a little troubled. how does the Expected value helps? with the dependance, I was "annoyed" by this part,  we have not learned how to open this expected value

Comment: Since conditional expectation (in particular conditional probabilities) is a very subtle issue, it would be best to consult with the instructor or course text being used. If you are asking how to see that $E(c^2 \mid c) = c^2$, then it follows from $E(Z_1\mid Z_2) = E(Z_1)$ if $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are independent. Constants are independent of every random variable.

Comment: I See, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observation: For now, I can give you a partial solution. maybe latter (or with some contribution), I can conclude the final part.

---

First, consider the following results. Given the Random Variables $U$ and $W$, we have:

R1: (Law of total expectation):$E[ E[U|W]] = E[U]$

R2: $E[h(U)E[W∣U]]=E[h(U)W]$ for every function $h:S \to \mathbb{R}$, where $S$ is the support set of $U$.

---

Now, we have that $Cov(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$.

also, by the problem statement, we have that $E[Y|X = t] = t^2$, which implies that

$$E[Y|X] = X^2  \qquad (1)$$

Applying the R1 over $E[Y|X], we have:

$$E[Y] = E[ E[Y|X] ] = E[X^2]  \qquad (2)$$

Applying the R2 with $h$ as the identity function, we have:

$$E[XY] = E[ X E[Y|X] ] = E[X\cdot X^2] = E[X^3]  \qquad (3)$$

In that way, we have that:

$$Cov(X,Y) = E[X^3] - E[X^2]E[X] \qquad (3)$$

Now we must investigate the values that Cov(X,Y) could take.

A) Cov(X,Y) = 0.

As pointed in the comments,  If $P(X = c) = 1$ for $c \in [-1,15]$, then $E[X^3] - E[X^2]E[X] = (c)^3 - c^2\cdot c = 0$. Therefore, $0$ is a possible value for $Cov(X,Y)$.

****This is the uncompleted part!****

Until this moment, I could not find any justification to confirm or refute the other possibilities. As soon I have the rest of the solution of this problem, i will update this answer.

---

reference: https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Probability_Theory/Probability_Mathematical_Statistics_and_Stochastic_Processes_(Siegrist)/04%3A_Expected_Value/4.07%3A_Conditional_Expected_Value

Comment: Wow, god lord, that answer, we have not learned anything from here almost ( R1 and R2 ).
This question should be banned from my course lol, how it is a test question and it was not learned... Thank you very much, I will go through the answer and try to understand it more!!

Comment: well, after a long time, actually I understood, basically I understand the formulas :\ but what you did is clear to me :)

Comment: @LearningToCode, maybe there is another way to solve this problem. This is just the more direct way that I find to solve the problem..

Comment: Neverthelesss, that answer is really good proofed, It is learning new stuff :)

Comment: Actually, to be honest, the answer is only 0 I think, right? since for all numbers between 0 and 15, you will get 0 ( since it is a*a*a, or (a*a)*a.......
the only bad number is -1, but it is not doing anything related to answers.

Comment: @LearningToCode, yes, I believe that it is impossible to the Covariance assume the value -16. But, until this moment, I could not find a formal justification for that.

Comment: It is all good :) Regarding the solution, it is all answers are right, it means, D
But thanks for the first way to get to 0, it was good :)